How can you send key combinations programatically?
Is there a way to send the key combination Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Right-Arrow through code? I am trying to send the active window to another workspace. The key combination works when used manually. I am trying to automate this using the Lazarus IDE.
I am running Linux Debian 6.10.6 with Gnome.

It's probably easier to programmatically send the active window to another workspace. See wmctrl and similar commands.
